# How do I forward email from Outlook with powershell

Tags: powershell, email, outlook, office-automation, forward

I need to forward the unread email from outlook using PowerShell.

I understand how to filter unread messages and create a new message. But how do I forward?

```
$Outlook = New-Object -ComObject Outlook.Application
$NameSpace = $Outlook.GetNamespace('mapi')
$Mailbox = $NameSpace.Stores['user@domain.ru'].GetRootFolder()
$Inbox = $Mailbox.Folders['Inbox']
$mail_unread = $Inbox.Items | Where-Object{ $_.unread -eq $true } | Select Subject, 
SenderEmailAddress, Body 
# Create new email
$mail = $Outlook.CreateItem(0)
$mail.to = "user2@domain.ru"
$mail.Subject = $mail_unread.Item(0).subject
$Mail.Body = $mail_unread.Item(0).body
$mail.Send()
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `MailItem.Forward` method instead of `Application.CreateItem` - it returns the new properly formatted message, you will only need to set the `To` property.

Also, do not loop through all items in a folder - it is horrible from the performance point of view. Use `items.Restrict` or `Items.Find/FindNext` with a query like `[Unread] = true`

Also note that your script only processes the first match (you can get multiple), and you never check that no matches were returned.

Comment: Tell us more, I don't have the $Outlook.MailItem.Forward method

Comment: See [MailItem.Forward](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.mailitem.forward(method))

Comment: Om your code, that woudl be `$mail = $mail_unread.Item(0).Forward()`

Answer (score 0):

> I understand how to filter unread messages and create a new message.

That is not correct when dealing with the Outlook object model. You need to use the `Find`/`FindNext` or `Restrict` methods of the Items class. They allow getting items that correspond to the specified search criteria, so you don't need to check every item in the folder which boots the overall performance. For example, the following C# code sample get all unread items from a folder and calls the `Forward` methods on each unread item:

```
using System.Text;
using System.Diagnostics;
// ...
private void FindAllUnreadEmails(Outlook.MAPIFolder folder)
{
    string searchCriteria = "[UnRead] = true";
    StringBuilder strBuilder = null;
    int counter = default(int);
    Outlook._MailItem mail = null;
    Outlook._MailItem forward = null;
    Outlook.Items folderItems = null;
    object resultItem = null;
    try
    {
        if (folder.UnReadItemCount > 0)
        {
            strBuilder = new StringBuilder();
            folderItems = folder.Items;
            resultItem = folderItems.Find(searchCriteria);
            while (resultItem != null)
            {
                if (resultItem is Outlook._MailItem)
                {
                    counter++;
                    mail = resultItem as Outlook._MailItem;
                    strBuilder.AppendLine("#" + counter.ToString() + 
                                          "\tSubject: " + mail.Subject);
                    forward = mail.Forward();
                    forward.To = "Eugene Astafiev";
                    forward.Send()
                     
                    Marshal.ReleaseComObject(forward); forward = null;
                }
                Marshal.ReleaseComObject(resultItem);
                resultItem = folderItems.FindNext();
            }
            if (strBuilder != null)
                Debug.WriteLine(strBuilder.ToString());
        }
        else
            Debug.WriteLine("There is no match in the " 
                                 + folder.Name + " folder.");
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
    }
    finally
    {
        if (folderItems != null) Marshal.ReleaseComObject(folderItems);
    }
}
```

The `Forward` method executes the `Forward` action for an item and returns the resulting copy as a `MailItem` object, so you don't need to create a new item in the code.

Read more about the `Find`/`FindNext` and `Restrict` methods in the articles that I wrote for the technical blog:

- [How To: Use Find and FindNext methods to retrieve Outlook mail items from a folder (C#, VB.NET)](https://www.add-in-express.com/creating-addins-blog/2011/09/20/outlook-find-findnext-retrieve-mail/)
- [How To: Use Restrict method to retrieve Outlook mail items from a folder](https://www.add-in-express.com/creating-addins-blog/2011/09/23/outlook-restrict-method-retrieve-mail/)

Comment: Thanks for the advice, but what will it look like on powershell?

Comment: The Outlook object model is common for all programming languages, the sample code shows the sequence of property and method calls you may use in your PowerShell script.